# Unity 3D, how to spawn objects, and modify their values?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

i try to make a simple 3D Rail Shooter, and i currently stuck on how to spawn the bullets for my Ship.

[image]

I want when i press on fire that the bullet gets spawned and gets shooted.
I created an empty gameObject as a child of my ship and put a script on it.

The problem is i currently stuck and i can't figure out how to get it done.
So im asking for help, what did i miss, what did i wrong?

Here is the script i came up with:

```
public Rigidbody rb;

private bool isMoving = false;
private bool isFirePressed = false;


void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rb.useGravity = false;
}

void Update()
{
    isFirePressed = Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1");
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        // the cube is going to move upwards in 10 units per second
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 100);
        isMoving = true;
        Debug.Log("fire");
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I guess you wanted to use your variable `isFirePressed`.

Then if that is a prefab I guess you rather want to `Instantiate` a new bullet:

```c#
if (isFirePressed)
{
    var newBullet = Instantiate (rb, transform);
    // the cube is going to move upwards in 10 units per second
    newBullet.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 100);
    newBullet.useGravity = false;
    isMoving = true;
    Debug.Log("fire");
}
```

You changed the velocity on the prefab which doesn't work.

---

Additionally note that the `velocity` is in World-Space coordinates. So currently you are shooting in world Z direction no matter where your plane is facing to.

I would rather use e.g.

```c#
newBullet.velocity = transform.forward * 100;
```

to shoot it in the direction your BulletEmitter is facing towards.

Comment: MissingComponentException: There is no 'Rigidbody' attached to the "Bullet Emitter" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Rigidbody to the game object "Bullet Emitter". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.

Comment: Yes exactly but i dont understand why i get this errormesage, to be precisly i understand the error but i dont know why? Does this mean i have to put the script somewhere else instead of the BulletEmitter(empty gameObject)?

Comment: You shouldn't use `rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();` at all .. since you don't want to get your own `Rigidbody` you rather want to use the Instantiated one...

Comment: ah, thats the problem, thanks a lot! I tryed it and know i get it.

Comment: @koki check my last update ;) you probably also want to shoot in the correct direction

Comment: thanks buddy, i came up with "newBullet.AddForce(transform.forward * bombThrust);"